# How to becomeFirstResponder TextField in TableViewCell when TextViewCell is invisible on the screen

Tags: ios, swift

Developing an iOS application with Xcode ver 9.2, Swift.

After the RightNavigationButtonAdd is tapped, I want to insert a TableViewCell at the beginning of the TableView and focus(becomeFirstResponder) the TextField in it.

When the inserted TableViewCell is visible, it works normally. But, when the inserted TableViewCell is invisible, an error occurred because of cellForRow returns nil.

Could you tell me how?

**Code of RightNavigationButtonAdd action**

```
@objc func RightNavigationButtonAdd(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // array is ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", ...]
    array.insert("", at: 0)
    // ttableView is @IBOutlet var ttableView: UITableView!
    // it is set to "No selection during editing"
    ttableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section:0)], with: .top)

    // when inserted cell is invisible, error occured:
    // "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
    let cell = ttableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0)) as! TableViewCell

    cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    cell.textField.placeholder = "input anything ..."
    ttableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0), at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

[Screenshot when inserted cell is visible -> it works normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chMlX.png)

[Screenshot when inserted cell is invisible -> error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq3bw.png)

Comment: Why are you not scrolling to row first and then later make the textfield first responder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost fine but you are crashing because that cell is out of range, so first you have to scroll to the beginning (to make it visible), then you'll be able to get the cell at such `IndexPath(row:0, section:0)`. You may check the documentation of [cellForRow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow):

> An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

Here the solution:

```
@objc func RightNavigationButtonAdd(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   array.insert("", at: 0)
   ttableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section:0)], with: .top)

   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.ttableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0), at: .top, animated: true)
    }) { (success) in
        let cell = self.ttableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0)) as! TableViewCell
        cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        cell.textField.placeholder = "input anything ..."
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was solved and I could what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by [Andrea Mugnaini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48125952/2305175) you need to scroll to that cell to make it's `textField` to `becomeFirstResponder()`. Now answering your question

> [...] cellForRow returns nil. Could you tell me how?

TableView has a pool of cells that are reused when you call `cellForRow(at:)`. Thus, when cell is no longer visible it goes back to pool and returned by `cellForRow(at:)` later. That's because no matter how many cells you need to display in your app you actually only need the amount of cells that fits your screen. You just reuse them. The problem with this approach is that even if you want to return cell that is out of the visible part of tableView, you can't do that because there is no cell currently displaying that row (they all busy displaying rows you see right now), and for that reason `cellForRow(at:)` returns nil.